# Сохранение html страницы с svg (с использованием mask) как pdf и проблемы при открытии в редакторах векторной графики

Tags: вёрстка, svg, google-chrome, pdf, chromium

Есть страница с svg элементом.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<svg xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="10 10 380 380" color="#1f26b4" version="1.1"><metadata><rdf:RDF><cc:Work rdf:about=""><dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format><dc:title/></cc:Work></rdf:RDF></metadata><g><g data-type="round"><defs><mask id="round-mask_25KtbDrFpl"><circle fill="white" r="190" cx="200" cy="200"/></mask></defs><circle mask="url(#round-mask_25KtbDrFpl)" stroke-linejoin="round" r="190" cx="200" cy="200" fill="none" stroke-width="362" stroke="#1f26b4" stroke-dasharray="0"/></g><g data-type="round"><defs><mask id="round-mask_aRXKnJsro9"><circle fill="white" r="186" cx="200" cy="200"/></mask></defs><circle mask="url(#round-mask_aRXKnJsro9)" stroke-linejoin="round" r="186" cx="200" cy="200" fill="none" stroke-width="8" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-dasharray="0"/></g></g></svg>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4o2ebxdu/1/

Круги сделаны через [маски](http://svg-art.ru/?p=1862). Этот подход отлично работает в браузерах и программах для просмотра svg.
Всё отображается корректно.

Если взять данную html страницу и открыть в chrome/chromium`e, **сохранить как PDF**, то получится вот такой PDF, который также корректно отображается в браузере или программах для просмотра PDF. https://dropmefiles.com/4EpAb

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако, если открыть этот PDF через Adobe Illustrator, Corel Draw или другие программы для работы с графикой, то начинаются проблемы. Выглядит вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно, это проблема иллюстратора, корела или хрома/хромиума. Однако, если маски не использовать, то подобных проблем естественно не наблюдается. Но подход с масками очень удобный.

**Вопрос: нет ли каких-то хитростей чтобы избежать этого эффекта?** Я пытался добавлять для mask overflow:hidden, пытался делать mask блочным элементом, это не помогает.

Пытался использовать use внутри маски, как было сказано в этом подобном вопросе https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63467045/incorrect-svg-mask-position-on-load-when-using-relative-positions-chrome

Тоже нет эффекта. PDF визуально правильный, но использовать его невозможно, ведь любые программы для работы с графикой отображают pdf неверно.

Причём, если открыть сам SVG в редакторе, то отображается корректно. Делаю вывод, что это баг хромиума/хрома. Но может есть какой-то хак-решение. Вот открытый .svg в иллюстраторе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD.**

Скрин из иллюстратора примеров с картинками.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Вот так выглядит ваш файл svg

```html
<svg xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="10 10 380 380" color="#1f26b4" version="1.1"><metadata><rdf:RDF><cc:Work rdf:about=""><dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format><dc:title/></cc:Work></rdf:RDF></metadata><g><g data-type="round"><defs><mask id="round-mask_25KtbDrFpl"><circle fill="white" r="190" cx="200" cy="200"/></mask></defs><circle mask="url(#round-mask_25KtbDrFpl)" stroke-linejoin="round" r="190" cx="200" cy="200" fill="none" stroke-width="362" stroke="#1f26b4" stroke-dasharray="0"/></g><g data-type="round"><defs><mask id="round-mask_aRXKnJsro9"><circle fill="white" r="186" cx="200" cy="200"/></mask></defs><circle mask="url(#round-mask_aRXKnJsro9)" stroke-linejoin="round" r="186" cx="200" cy="200" fill="none" stroke-width="8" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-dasharray="0"/></g></g></svg>
```

Мешает служебная информация, которую оставил векторный редактор и возможно была выбрана опция `Remove whitespace`

Чтобы, как-то разобраться в коде оптимизировал ваш файл с помощью [SVG-EDITOR](https://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg-editor)

Вот что получилось:

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="380" height="380" viewBox="10 10 380 380" color="#1f26b4" style="border:1px solid">
  <g data-type="round">
    <defs>
      <mask id="round-mask_25KtbDrFpl">
        <circle fill="white" r="190" cx="200" cy="200"/>
      </mask>
    </defs>
    <circle mask="url(#round-mask_25KtbDrFpl)" stroke-linejoin="round" r="190" cx="200" cy="200" fill="none" stroke-width="362" stroke="#1f26b4" stroke-dasharray="0"/>
  </g>
  <g data-type="round">
    <defs>
      <mask id="round-mask_aRXKnJsro9">
        <circle fill="white" r="186" cx="200" cy="200"/>
      </mask>
    </defs>
    <circle mask="url(#round-mask_aRXKnJsro9)" stroke-linejoin="round" r="186" cx="200" cy="200" fill="none" stroke-width="8" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-dasharray="0"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Рамка это граница холста SVG, который имеет физические размеры 380х380 при

```
<mask id="round-mask_25KtbDrFpl">
        <circle fill="white" r="190" cx="200" cy="200"/>
      </mask>
```

Края окружности находится вплотную `190 * 2 = 380` к границам холста.
Хоть вы и не указали здесь `stroke` по умолчанию она равна 1px.
Внешняя половина этой строки находится вне холста SVG и поэтому подрезается.
Мы с вами не знаем, как происходит конвертация в `pdf`. Может при конвертации, эта **распространенная ошибка** как-то учитывается, поэтому файл PDF выглядит нормально. Но при обратной конвертации в векторный редактор эта ошибка вылазит наружу.

Тем более вы заполняете фигуру широкой строкой 362px, половина её тоже выходит наружу, потом вы режете её другой маской, короче процесс очень запутанный. Поэтому возможны любые сюрпризы, тем более браузеры не всегда одинаково отрабатывают эти процессы.

Вывод один, старайтесь подбирать размеры SVG холста таким образом, чтобы был гарантированный зазор между краем холста и внешней части SVG элемента.

И вообще, это плохая практика, заполнять фигуру очень широкой строкой, так как её вторая половина выходит наружу и с ней надо что-то делать.
Есть же команда `fill="#1f26b4"` и не надо никаких масок. Они нужны для более продвинутых вещей.

Вот пример, пробуйте проделать с ним те же конвертации в pdf и обратно

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="380" height="380" viewBox="0 0 380 380"  style="border:1px solid">
  
        <circle fill="#1f26b4" r="180" cx="190" cy="190"/> 
          <circle fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="4" r="170" cx="190" cy="190"/> 
            <circle fill="white"  r="12" cx="190" cy="190"/> 
</svg>
```

**Пример для проверки, мешает ли маска**

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="380" height="380" viewBox="0 0 380 380"  style="border:1px solid">
   <defs>
      <mask id="msk"> 
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
       <circle fill="white"  r="160" cx="190" cy="190"/> 
      </mask>
   </defs>   
   
        <circle fill="#1f26b4" r="180" cx="190" cy="190"/> 
          <circle fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="4" r="170" cx="190" cy="190"/>  
         <image mask="url(#msk)" y="30" href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vccyb.jpg" width="100%" 
    <height="100%" /> 
            
</svg>
```

Comment: Ранее вы подсказали ответ на вопрос как сделать заполнение элемента обводкой только внутрь. Это решение прекрасно работает и для полигонов (треугольников), rect или circle элементов. Да и в целом для любых форм. И отображается шикарно в браузерах и просмотре PDF. И правда либо это браузеры исправляют ошибку, а редакторы нет, либо это в редакторах ошибка. А причина использования масок кроется в прошлом вопросе - сделать вот такой же пример, но без масок - крайне непросто. https://jsfiddle.net/wv5j9f0q/1/ Я увидел, что маски работают и для cirlce и для rect и переписал их тоже на маски.

Comment: И действительно это решило кучу проблем и дало универсальное решение для браузеров. Они отлично отображают это. Но вот засада с хромиумом и PDF (я использовал движок хромиума для генерации PDF). Хотя как ни странно, https://alafr.github.io/SVG-to-PDFKit/examples/demo.htm вот pdfkit справился с задачей и их pdf с svg из примера открывается корректно в редакторах. Но у pdfkit другие проблемы есть. А раз pdfkit справился, видимо всё-таки баг хромиума.

Comment: @Floyat И тогда для меня была загадка, когда отвечал на предыдущий вопрос, зачем заполнять широкой строкой, когда есть `fill` Если вам так хочется использовать маски для этой цели, попробуйте выполнить мою рекомендацию - отодвинутся от края холста SVG/

Comment: У меня конструктор определенной продукции и есть редактор с ползунками для изменения толщины обводки для кругов, для прямоугольников и треугольников. И вот этот пример иллюстрирует идеальное решение задачи - https://jsfiddle.net/wv5j9f0q/1/ Решение ваше и оно прекрасное (тут просто упрощенный пример). Но без масок сделать тоже самое - задача не очень простая.

Comment: И эта задача станет ещё сложней, когда к ползунку толщины обводки добавится второй ползунок - размер треугольника. Я просто не очень хочу показывать на широкую общественность проект в котором это используется, но маски пока единственное рабочее и удобное решение. Но вот засада с PDF возникла. Думал может кто знает почему так получается, поэтому сделал на примере круга для простоты. Хотя такая же проблема наблюдается и для прямоугольников и треугольников.

Comment: @Floyat Да я разве против, сейчас сделаю пример с маской для картинки, попробуйте его конвертнуть по той же схеме, как делали, надо же разобраться, маски мешают или к краю слишком близко

Comment: @Floyat попробуйте конвертнуть на новом примере с маской

Comment: Добавил в пост скрин. Дело всё-таки в масках. Удивительно для меня на самом деле, до этого использовали движок хромиума для генерации PDF для очень сложных элементов, не только векторных. Ни разу не было косяков. А тут вот так. Хотя опять же, PDF то корректный. То есть фактически хромиум справился с оговорочкой. Проблемы только когда открываешь в редакторе векторной графики. А без масок тоже самое откроется корректно, я уверен.

Comment: @Floyat Сейчас немного изменю маску, ещё раз попробуете?

Comment: Да, конечно. Вам спасибо большое за помощь.

Comment: @Floyat пробуйте

Comment: @Floyat похоже, это действительно баг хромиума. Ушел отдыхать. Завтра надо попробовать в штатном конвертере pdf

Comment: Прикрепил. Иное отображение. Но одинаковое и в кореле, и в inkscape и в иллюстраторе. На прошлом примере также было. Все 3 редактора отображают одинаково, но не так, как показывается в pdf.

Comment: @Floyat понятно. Ушёл. Спокойной ночи

Comment: Да вот, к сожалению, у других конвертеров миллион других бед. Например, со шрифтами. Если хромиум примет <style> тег в svg со шрифтом (font-face) в виде ссылки на WOFF/TTF файл или этот же шрифт в base64 и создаст PDF 1 в 1 как браузер бы их отобразил, то другие с этим совсем не справятся никак. Или почти никак. Хромиум был идеален во всем до этого случая. Поэтому у меня предположение, что придется отказываться от масок и биться с решением задачи с изменением размера обводки только внутрь без масок.