# Изменение толщины обводки svg фигур только внутрь относительно осевой линии stroke. Часть 2

Tags: javascript, вёрстка, svg, математика, геометрия

https://jsfiddle.net/ru8fzeya/5/

```js
//polygon
function changeStrokePoly() {
   var poly = document.getElementById("poly"),
         isw  = document.getElementById("isw-poly"); 
   poly.setAttribute("stroke-width",isw.value);
};

function changeSizePoly(){
   var poly     = document.getElementById("poly"),
       polyMask = document.getElementById("msk-poly"),
       isz      = document.getElementById("isz-poly"); 
 
   var _getCoordinates = function(scale){
     var viewBox   = 400,
         placeSize = 380 * (scale / 100),
                 h         = placeSize * (Math.sqrt(3) / 2);

            var offsetX = (viewBox - placeSize) / 2,
                offsetY = (viewBox - h) / 2,
                coordinates = [
                    {
                        x : (placeSize / 2 + offsetX),
                        y : offsetY
                    },
                    {
                        x : (offsetX),
                        y : (h + offsetY),
                    },
                    {
                        x : (placeSize + offsetX),
                        y : (h + offsetY)
                    }
                ];
        
        return coordinates;
   }
   
   var coordinates = _getCoordinates(isz.value),
         coordinatesString = coordinates[0].x + ' ' + coordinates[0].y + ' ' + coordinates[1].x + ' ' + coordinates[1].y + ' ' + coordinates[2].x + ' ' + coordinates[2].y;
   
   poly.setAttribute('points', coordinatesString);
   polyMask.setAttribute('points', coordinatesString); 
};

//circle
function changeStrokeCircle() {
   var circle = document.getElementById("circle"),
         isw  = document.getElementById("isw-circle"); 
   circle.setAttribute("stroke-width",isw.value);
};

function changeSizeCircle(){
   var circle     = document.getElementById("circle"),
       circleMask = document.getElementById("msk-circle"),
       isz        = document.getElementById("isz-circle"); 
 
   circle.setAttribute('r', isz.value);
   circleMask.setAttribute('r', isz.value);
};

//rect
function changeStrokeRect() {
   var rect = document.getElementById("rect"),
         isw  = document.getElementById("isw-rect"); 
   rect.setAttribute("stroke-width",isw.value);
};

function changeSizeRect(){
   var rect      = document.getElementById("rect"),
       rectMask  = document.getElementById("msk-rect"),
       isz       = document.getElementById("isz-rect"),
       value     = isz.value,
       maxWidth  = 300,
       maxHeight = 100,
       width     = maxWidth * value / 100,
       height    = maxHeight * value / 100;
  
   rect.setAttribute('width', width);
   rect.setAttribute('height', height);
   
   rectMask.setAttribute('width', width);
   rectMask.setAttribute('height', height);
};
```

```html
<div>
 <div>
 Polygon--
 <input id="isw-poly" type="range" min="1" value="30" max="219"  oninput="changeStrokePoly()"/>
 <input id="isz-poly" type="range" min="10" value="100" max="100"  oninput="changeSizePoly()"/>
 </div>
 <div>
 Circle-----
 <input id="isw-circle" type="range" min="1" value="30" max="360"  oninput="changeStrokeCircle()"/>
 <input id="isz-circle" type="range" min="10" value="180" max="180"  oninput="changeSizeCircle()"/>
 </div>
 
 <div>
  Rect-------
  <input id="isw-rect" type="range" min="1" value="30" max="100"  oninput="changeStrokeRect()"/>
  <input id="isz-rect" type="range" min="10" value="100" max="100"  oninput="changeSizeRect()"/>
 </div>
</div>

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="400" viewBox="0 0 800 400" >
<defs>
<mask id="msk1">
<polygon id="msk-poly" fill="#fff" points="200 35.5 10 364.5 390 364.5"></polygon>
</mask> 
<mask id="msk2">
<circle id="msk-circle" fill="#fff" cx="600" cy="200" r="180"></circle>
</mask>
<mask id="msk3">
<rect id="msk-rect" fill="#fff" x="200" y="-100" width="300" height="100"></rect>
</mask> 
</defs> 
    <polygon id="poly" mask="url(#msk1)" fill="none" stroke-width="30" stroke="red" points="200 35.5 10 364.5 390 364.5"></polygon>
    <circle id="circle" mask="url(#msk2)" fill="none" stroke-width="30" stroke="green" cx="600" cy="200" r="180"></circle>
    <rect id="rect" mask="url(#msk3)" fill="none" stroke-width="30" stroke="blue" x="200" y="-100" width="300" height="100"></rect>
</svg>
```

Есть 3 фигуры: **равносторонний** треугольник, круг и прямоугольник. Также есть ползунки для изменения **толщины обводки** и изменения **размера фигур**. Между собой фигуры независимые. Как видно в примере, обводка фигур изменяется **только внутрь**. Внешняя обводка обрезается, спасибо за это mask элементу и [@Alexandr_TT](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/28748/alexandr-tt) за помощь в этом [решении](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1254103/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B8-svg-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD/1254538), а также за альтернативное решение в этом же вопросе.

Но т.к. с масками/clip-path не всё идеально (подробнее о проблеме написано [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1257031/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-html-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D1%81-svg-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-mask-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-pdf-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82/1257312)), то я ищу, вероятно, более сложное с точки зрения подхода, но более универсальное, решение, которое будет основано на математике и геометрии.

Ожидаю, что можно решить задачу для каждой фигуры, используя **только один polygon**, **один rect** и **один circle** соответственно. Без масок, без clip-path и других внешних элементов. То есть только пересчётом координат треугольника, ширины и высоты прямоугольника и радиуса круга.

Дополнительные ограничения:

1. Координаты треугольника, начальный радиус или координаты центра круга, а также ширина и высота прямоугольника - произвольные. В примере их значения - просто пример. Треугольник всегда равносторонний (для упрощения).
2. Нельзя менять viewBox, использовать css, маски и clip-path.
3. Обводка ни при каких обстоятельствах не выступает за границы фигур.
4. Обводкой можно полностью "заполнить" фон внутри фигуры.
5. Обводка и размер фигур регулируется через ползунки.
6. В самом SVG может быть множество различных других фигур и элементов, решение не должно на них влиять.

Вопрос: как это можно сделать?

Вот пример из которого убрано всё лишнее: https://jsfiddle.net/ru8fzeya/6/
Оставлены только фигуры и изменение толщины обводки/размера. Но стандартное поведение для stroke - расширение в обе стороны, а необходимо добиться такого же результата как в примере  с масками, но без масок.

Comment: Вам нужен именно равносторонний треугольник или произвольный многоугольник?

Comment: Достаточно равностороннего треугольника.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решение основано на принципе нахождения центра и расчета смещения, хотя для каждой из приведенной фигуры оно расчитывается несколько иначе.

[image: графическое представление]

Итак к примеру есть какая-то фигура мы хотим увеличить толщину обводки на 1 пиксель, естественно он увеличит `видимый размер` фигуры именно это и нужно компенсировать (уменьшить фигуру) что схематически изображено на рисунке выше.

*В связи с необходимостью расчета компенсаций нет смысла разделять расчеты на 2 функции для размера и толщины линии.*

Для **круга** самое простое: увеличение радиуса на 1 пиксель приводит к увеличению диаметра на 2 пикселя:

- формула перерасчета радиуса `радиус - толщина_обводки / 2`;

Для **прямоугольника** чуть сложнее:

- формула позиции по x:  `начальная_позиция_x + толщина_обводки / 2`
- формула позиции по y:  `начальная_позиция_x + толщина_обводки / 2`
- формула ширины: `ширина - толщина_обводки`
- формула высоты: `высота - толщина_обводки`

Для **полигона** еще сложнее:

- нужно получить все точки (например из html разметки)
- согласно основной идее найти `центр` откуда точки будут расходится/сходится
- дополнительно находим `расстояние от центра` и `угол в градусах` для каждой точки
- расчет новой координаты для х

`центр + (расстояние_от_центра - толшина_обводки + размер) * косинус(угла)`

- расчет новой координаты для y

`центр + (расстояние_от_центра - толшина_обводки + размер) * синус(угла)`

Ниже приведено решение, код не очень оптимизирован, но читаем, единственно не решенный момент заключается в том что если толщина линии больше радиуса то начинаются перекрытия свойственные svg и фигура проподает или "открашивается", поэтому сначала лучше выставить размер при толщине обводки равной 1 пиксель а потом уже добавлять толщину, в целом я думаю не составит труда добавить коррекцию для диапазона величин исходя из размера фигуры чтобы не было подобных наложений.

```js
    //polygon
    const getPolyPoints = ( id ) => {
      var poly = document.getElementById( id );
      const points = poly.getAttribute( 'points' ).split(' ');
      const result = []
      for ( let i = 0; i < points.length; i += 2 ){
        result.push({
          x: Number( points[i] ),
          y: Number( points[i + 1] )
        })
      }  
      return result;
    }

    // находим усредненный центр всех точек
    const getPolyCenter = ( points ) => {
      let x = 0,
          y = 0;
      for( let i = 0 ; i < points.length; i++ ){
        x += points[i].x;
        y += points[i].y;
      }
      x /= points.length;
      y /= points.length;
      return({ x, y });
    }

    const setPointsInfo = ( points, center ) => {
      for(let i = 0 ; i < points.length; i++){
        // находим растояние из центра 
        points[i].r = 
          Math.sqrt( Math.pow(Math.abs(points[i].x - center.x), 2) 
                  +  Math.pow(Math.abs(points[i].y - center.y), 2)
          )
        // находим угол в градусах
        // из центра до точки
        points[i].a = 
          Math.atan2(
            points[i].y - center.y,
            points[i].x - center.x
          ) / ( Math.PI/180 );
      } 
    } 

    const points = getPolyPoints("poly");
    const center = getPolyCenter(points);
    setPointsInfo(points, center)

    function changePoly() {
      var poly = document.getElementById("poly"),
          isw  = document.getElementById("isw-poly"), 
          isz  = document.getElementById("isz-poly"); 
      // высчитываем новые координаты (можно добавить поворот)
      let pts = "";
      for(let i = 0; i < points.length; i++){
        const x = center.x + (points[i].r - isw.value + Number(isz.value)) 
          * Math.cos(points[i].a  * ( Math.PI/180 ))
        const y = center.y + (points[i].r - isw.value + Number(isz.value)) 
          * Math.sin(points[i].a  * ( Math.PI/180 ))
        pts += `${x} ${y} ` 
      } 
      poly.setAttribute("stroke-width",isw.value);
      poly.setAttribute('points', pts); 
    };

    //circle
    // не нужно дополнительных переменных поскольку
    // координаты считаются от центра
    function changeCircle() {
       var circle = document.getElementById("circle"),
           isw  = document.getElementById("isw-circle"),
           isz  = document.getElementById("isz-circle"); 
       circle.setAttribute("stroke-width",isw.value);
       // рассчет смещения
       circle.setAttribute('r', isz.value - isw.value/2);
    };

    //rect
    // дополнительные преременные для правильного смещения  
    const rectOrigX =  +document.getElementById("rect").getAttribute("x");
    const rectOrigY =  +document.getElementById("rect").getAttribute("y");

    function changeRect() {
       var rect = document.getElementById("rect"),
           isw  = document.getElementById("isw-rect"),
           isz       = document.getElementById("isz-rect"),
           maxWidth  = 300,
           maxHeight = 100,
           width     = maxWidth * isz.value / 100,
           height    = maxHeight * isz.value / 100;
       
       rect.setAttribute( "stroke-width", isw.value );
       // рассчет смещения
       rect.setAttribute( "x", rectOrigX + Number(isw.value) / 2 );
       rect.setAttribute( "y", rectOrigY + Number(isw.value) / 2 );
       rect.setAttribute( "width", width -  isw.value );
       rect.setAttribute( "height", height -  isw.value );
    };

   // корректируем изначальную отрисовку
   // в идеале лучше создать классы для фигур
   // которые будут их пересчитывать
   changePoly();
   changeCircle();
   changeRect();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      Polygon
      <input id="isw-poly" type="range" min="1" value="15" max="219"  oninput="changePoly()"/>
      <input id="isz-poly" type="range" min="10" value="10" max="100"  oninput="changePoly()"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      Circle
      <input id="isw-circle" type="range" min="1" value="15" max="360"  oninput="changeCircle()"/>
      <input id="isz-circle" type="range" min="10" value="180" max="180"  oninput="changeCircle()"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      Rect
      <input id="isw-rect" type="range" min="1" value="15" max="100"  oninput="changeRect()"/>
      <input id="isz-rect" type="range" min="10" value="100" max="100"  oninput="changeRect()"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="400" viewBox="0 0 800 400" >
    <polygon id="poly" fill="none" stroke-width="15" stroke="red" points="200 35.5 10 364.5 390 364.5"></polygon>
    <circle id="circle" fill="none" stroke-width="15" stroke="green" cx="600" cy="200" r="180"></circle>
    <rect id="rect"  fill="none" stroke-width="15" stroke="blue" x="200" y="-100" width="300" height="100"></rect>
  </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

> А т.к. с масками не всё идеально (об этом написано в этом вопросе, а
> само решение с масками отсюда), то вопрос такой - как добиться такого
> же эффекта как в примере, но без масок?

Давайте попробуем заменить маски на `clipPath`

Использовал ваш код из вопроса. Заменил маску на clipPath. Принцип обрезки тот же, как и у маски, - всё что вне фигуры, заданной в определении клипа, будет обрезано. Внутреннее содержание будет показано. Поэтому строка будет расти только внутрь.

**Добавлена координатная сетка для визуализации изменений.**

```js
function changeStroke() {
   var poly = document.getElementById("poly"),
         isw  = document.getElementById("isw"); 
   poly.setAttribute("stroke-width",isw.value);
};

function changeSize(){
   var poly     = document.getElementById("poly"),
       polyMask = document.getElementById("msk-poly"),
       isz      = document.getElementById("isz"); 
 
   var _getCoordinates = function(scale){
     var viewBox   = 400,
         placeSize = 380 * (scale / 100),
                 h         = placeSize * (Math.sqrt(3) / 2);

            var offsetX = (viewBox - placeSize) / 2,
                offsetY = (viewBox - h) / 2,
                coordinates = [
                    {
                        x : (placeSize / 2 + offsetX),
                        y : offsetY
                    },
                    {
                        x : (offsetX),
                        y : (h + offsetY),
                    },
                    {
                        x : (placeSize + offsetX),
                        y : (h + offsetY)
                    }
                ];
        
        return coordinates;
   }
   
   var coordinates = _getCoordinates(isz.value),
         coordinatesString = coordinates[0].x + ' ' + coordinates[0].y + ' ' + coordinates[1].x + ' ' + coordinates[1].y + ' ' + coordinates[2].x + ' ' + coordinates[2].y;
   
   poly.setAttribute('points', coordinatesString);
   polyMask.setAttribute('points', coordinatesString);
   
};
```

```html
<div> <input id="isw" type="range" min="1" value="4" max="219"  oninput="changeStroke()"/>
     <input id="isz" type="range" min="10" value="100" max="100"  oninput="changeSize()"/> </div>
    
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1000" height="1000" viewBox="-20 -20 1050 1050" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >
    <defs>
    <clipPath id="msk">
    <polygon id="msk-poly" fill="#fff"  points="200 35.5 10 364.5 390 364.5"></polygon>
    </clipPath>   
    
    <pattern id="p10" width="10" height="10" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <path d="M 10 0 L 0 0 0 10" fill="none" stroke="gray" stroke-width="0.5"/>
      </pattern>
      <pattern id="p100" width="100" height="100" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <rect width="100" height="100" fill="url(#p10)"/>
        <path d="M 100 0 L 0 0 0 100" fill="none" stroke="gray" stroke-width="1"/>
      </pattern>
    </defs>  
    <rect width="1000" height="1000" fill="url(#p100)" /> 
      <!-- Вертикальный блок цифр -->

      <text x="-15" y="0">0,0</text> 
       <text x="-20" y="100" >100</text> 
        <text x="-20" y="200">200</text> 
         <text x="-20" y="300">300</text> 
          <text x="-20" y="400">400</text> 
           <text x="-20" y="500">500</text> 
          <text x="-20" y="600">600</text> 
         <text x="-20" y="700">700</text> 
        <text x="-20" y="800">800</text>
       <text x="-20" y="900">900</text> 
      <text x="-20" y="1000">1000</text> 
          <!-- Горизонтальный блок --> 
     <text x="100" y="-5" >100</text> 
       <text x="200" y="-5" >200</text> 
        <text x="300" y="-5">300</text> 
         <text x="400" y="-5">400</text> 
          <text x="500" y="-5">500</text>    
         <text x="600" y="-5">600</text> 
         <text x="700" y="-5">700</text> 
        <text x="800" y="-5">800</text>
       <text x="900" y="-5">900</text>  
      <text x="990" y="-5">1000</text>   
      
        <polygon id="poly" clip-path="url(#msk)" fill="none" stroke-width="4" stroke="red"  points="200 35.5 10 364.5 390 364.5"></polygon>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Как и в прошлые разы, изящное решение в целом. Открыл в хроме, задал обводку 180, сохранил как PDF. Открываю PDF в иллюстраторе - 100% соответствие, корел и inkscape не справились совсем. Они открыли треугольники с обводкой 4, игнорируя clip-path. Далее попробовал сохранить только как svg и открыть в редакторах векторной графики. Иллюстратор и inkscape справились. Корел открыл треугольник с внешней обводкой, то есть совсем не смог в clip-path. Печальненько. Я понимаю, что это или проблема отдельных программ или движка хрома при переводе в pdf.

Comment: Вероятно, маски и clip-path - достаточно нестандартные решения, которые не особо поддерживаются векторными редакторами/pdf генераторами. Я не указал это в этой задаче, но я ищу альтернативное решение именно с той целью, чтобы получить svg, который откроет любой популярный векторный редактор в svg или после перевода в pdf. Поэтому, я предполагаю, что рабочим будет решение только пересчитывать координаты треугольника по какой-то формуле, ну то есть используя только 1 элемент - polygon. И оперируя только с ним. Хотя я понимаю, что пересчитать координаты для определенной обводки - не просто.

Comment: Во всяком случае мы в составе нескольких человек бьемся над этой задачей уже не один день...

Comment: @Floyat Разработчики векторных редакторов и конверторов наверняка мало думают об обратном ковертировании. Конвертируется в PDF, ну и хорошо. А вот обратная конвертация в векторный редактор, я думаю их мало беспокоит. Поэтому, от такого крутого замеса, туда-сюда вот эти проблемы и происходят. Будет свободное окошко, попробую ещё вариант сделать с паттернами

Comment: Да я понимаю это. Просто если конвертировать polygon/rect/circle/path туда-сюда (в PDF и обратно) с любыми обводками и любых форм хоть сколько раз, они всегда будут открываться корректно всеми редакторами, провели такие тесты уже. То есть обратное конвертирование для всех стандартных фигур поддерживается. Поэтому предполагаю, что может есть какое-то решение, которые будет работать в любом редакторе. В любом случае спасибо вам за помощь. Я не знал до этого ни про такие особенности масок, ни про такое решение с clip-path.

Comment: Я подожду ещё немного. Может кто подскажет с решением с точки зрения геометрии. Потому что сейчас у меня надежды на именно такое решение (с пересчётом координат при изменении толщины обводки), если, конечно, такое вообще возможно. Предполагаю, что крайне не просто, но возможно. Если так не получится решить задачу, то, конечно ваш ответ отмечу правильным. По факту всё верно, альтернативный метод вы показали и он работает.